# How do I mock static method that calls other private static methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

How can I mock this method below that calls another private static method?

```
public class testA {
    public static JSONObject retrieveOrder(String orderId)
                throws Exception {
            String url = "/contract/"; 
            JSONObject order = new JSONObject();
            order.put("orderId", orderId);  
            return orderPOST(url, order);
        }

    private static orderPOST(String url, JSONObject order) {
        return orderPOSTString(url, order.toString());
    }

    private static orderPOSTString (String url, String order) {
         //do another call to method which will return JSONObject
    }
}
```

How can I just mock `retrieveOrder` method only as I don't care any of those private methods? And as for those private static methods, I can't modify any of them so have to accept them as is.

This is my test:

```
@Test
    public void testRetrieveOrderMethod() throws Exception {
        String url = "/contract/"; 
        JSONObject order = new JSONObject();
        order.put("orderId", orderId);  
        PowerMockito.spy(testA.class);
        PowerMockito.doReturn(url, order.toString()).when(testA.class, "orderPOST", Matchers.any(), Matchers.any());
        JSONObject retrieved = testA.retrieveOrder("12345");
    }
```

Please let me know if I miss anything here. I keep getting `NullPointerException` as I suspect it's actually calling those private methods.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thing is: **even** your *class under test* doesn't compile! Those two static methods are missing **return types**. Start by putting up *reasonable* input here! And clearly explain **what** you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `when(testA.class, "orderPOST"...` is mocking `orderPost` method.

If you want to mock just the `retrieveOrder` method and want to ignore the other ones, your test class should be:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) // needed for powermock to work
// class that has static method and will be mocked must be in PrepareForTest
@PrepareForTest({ testA.class })
public class MyTestClass {

    @Test
    public void testRetrieveOrderMethod() throws Exception {
        // JSON object you want to return
        JSONObject order = new JSONObject();
        order.put("orderId", "whatever value you want to test");

        PowerMockito.spy(testA.class);
        // retrieveOrder will return order object
        PowerMockito.doReturn(order).when(testA.class, "retrieveOrder", Mockito.anyString());

        // call static method
        JSONObject retrieved = testA.retrieveOrder("12345");

        // do the assertions you need with retrieved
    }
}
```

You could also change `spy` and `doReturn` to:

```java
PowerMockito.mockStatic(testA.class);
Mockito.when(testA.retrieveOrder(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(order);
```

Both will work the same way.

Comment: I have update my test code but now I run into two different error depending on how I mock it.
1.  Is there a way that I don't have to include in PrepareForTest.  If I include testA.class in PrepareForTest, it would not work for code coverage purpose.
2.  But if I don't include in PrepareForTest, I would get org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
........
3.  If I change to mockStatic and when, then of course I got org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException.
4.  What's about Whitebox.invokeMethod approach?

Comment: If you want to mock a static method with PowerMockito, you must use `RunWith` and `PrepareForTest` (it's seem to be [mandatory](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockStatic)) There seems to be a [bug with PowerMockito and code coverage](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/422), not sure if it is (or will be) fixed. I've never used `Whitebox`, so I don't know if it would work.

Comment: I have to end up having those private static methods to run as I can't figure out a way to ignore them.  Things are working for me now.